# What does Zero pixel value in NDBI mean?

Tags: pixel

NDBI > 0 indicates built up, while NDVI <0 indicates no built up value. What does NDBI = 0 mean?

Comment: I don't think 0 is actually possible, because NDVI and NDBI is a division formula. There must be something wrong in the equation.

Comment: Not all NDVI > 0 are built up, could be sand also. Check this: https://is.muni.cz/el/1431/podzim2012/Z8114/um/35399132/35460312/ndbi.pdf

Answer (score 5):

NDBI (like NDVI) is an index that can be useful to highlight built up areas, but it is not possible to use a single threshold to determine with 100% certainty if the observed land cover is built up. The use of indices should therefore be done carefully: while they can be very powerfull, in some cases it doesn't work and you need to use all spectral bands. In the case of NDBI, it seems to work better than NDVI but, as far as I know, it hasn't been tested on large areas. On the paper mentioned by @aldo_tapia, there are confusions with diverse bare soil types (barren, sand and fallows) but the majority of the area is covered by water, farmland, urban and forest, so the results are likely to be less good in arid areas. Also note that they did not make atmospheric corrections on the input image, so this could affect their threshold value.

In any case, the threshold to use depends on what type of error is the less problematic in your study. If you want to make sure that you detect all potential built up areas, then you could include zero (it is theorically possible to have zeros with normalized difference indices, even if it is unfrequent), but if you want to reduce the amount of false positive, then you should use something like > 0.05 (even if some types of bare soil will not be distinguished by NDBI in any case).

Answer (score -2):

NDBI and NDVI are formulas that rely on a simple division:

> NDVI = (NIR - red) / (NIR + red)
>
> NDBI = (SWIR - NIR) / (SWIR + NIR)

NIR, red, and SWIR are percentages reflected off the surface/object. If this is exactly 0, it means there is no vegetation at all.

Source: https://earthobservatory.nasa.gov/Features/MeasuringVegetation/measuring_vegetation_2.php

Thanks for the correction in the comments.

Comment: What about when NIR = red or SWIR =  NIR?

Comment: @RJJoling That doesn't make sense; the values used in the formula are not wavelengths, but ratios of spectral reflectances taking on values [0, 1]. See, for example, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalized_difference_vegetation_index, which states "the NDVI itself thus varies between -1.0 and +1.0." 0 is a part of that set.

Comment: It seems to me that this question requires exactly that explanation/discussion. I think it's completely misleading to say that "neither NIR and red nor SWIR and NIR frequencies can be equal to each other". The NIR, SWIR variables are ratios, not frequencies, and their ratios can certainly be equal. If you want to split hairs about digital signals and floating point round-offs, fair enough. But mathematically, NDVI can certainly take on the value of zero. If zero is not allowed, then what range can NDVI take? Is 0.00000001 acceptable? Etc.

Comment: If the surface reflects half the incoming SWIR and half the incoming NIR then NDBI =(1/2 - 1/2) / (1/2+1/2) which = 0 which is perfectly plausible, within measurement error.

Comment: You are correct jon: https://earthobservatory.nasa.gov/Features/MeasuringVegetation/measuring_vegetation_2.php I edited my answer, thanks.

Comment: I stand corrected, but an NDBI of 0 still makes no sense.

Comment: @RJJoling what do you mean "makes no sense"? Because it can't be interpreted as indicating built up/non-built up? That's still sensible, it means the underlying surface isn't strongly typical of either.